# Page Speed Insight error diagnosing performance

Tags: prestashop, pagespeed

I am trying to check a website with Page Speed Insights but it gives me this error and show a big JSON:

Oops! Something went wrong.
generic::internal: Error unmarshalling JSON into proto: {"lighthouseVersion":"10.0.2","requestedUrl"......................................................................................................................................................

I have tried disabling the firewall on server and reverting some changes I have done in the page recently but nothing works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/14911) of lighthouse, which has been fixed at v10.1.0, but need some time to ship to PageSpeed Insights :)